# Django IntegerField in PostgreSQL getting a "numeric field overflow" error at 1000

Tags: django, database, postgresql, integer

Context: I have moved my project from a local SQLite database into an AWS RDS PostgreSQL database.  It was a blank database so migrations went fine, but now that I'm testing actually saving data, I'm getting an error on an IntegerField.

models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    amount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

test.py

```
testItem = Item(name="Test item valued at 1000")
testItem.description = "please delete"
testItem.amount = 1000
testItem.save()
```

And so I'm getting this error:

```
numeric field overflow
DETAIL:  A field with precision 5, scale 2 must round to an absolute value less than 10^3.
```

The error is pretty obvious, I dial it back down a bit and it's fine.  But I was under the impression that IntegerFields can go up to 2147483647.  I have no clue why there's precision and scale involved with an integer.  I'm just not quite sure what's happening, does my database think this is a decimal?  I ran a fresh migration that went off without a hitch, and the field has never been a DecimalField previously.  I feel like I'm probably missing something extremely simple here.

Comment: Can you post the code for the appropriate migration? Also can you inspect your database and post the exact datatype that the `amount` column has?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do either of those things.  I'll google around and see if I get anything.

Comment: The migration sql is:

-- Create model Item
--
CREATE TABLE "storefront_item" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "name" varchar(100) NOT NULL, "description" text NULL, "amount" integer NOT NULL);


So it looks like amount is an integer.

Comment: What do you get when you run this on the database directly?: `SELECT data_type, numeric_precision, numeric_precision_radix FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'storefront_item' AND column_name = 'amount'`

Comment: I actually don't have psql installed, I don't suppose I can run it off AWS RDS console somehow?

Comment: Probably not the ideal solution, I went into RDS, deleted the database and started from scratch.  Everything works fine now.  I can't even pin what I did differently.  I noticed that ALL IntegerFields in my previous projects would have decimals associated with them in the admin pages, so I'm not really sure what went wrong.  Thanks for the help everyone!